# jQuery fadeto animation not workings

Tags: jquery

this is my code its the html and the css is in another file which i didnt put i set the opacity to 0.5 in the css for the div and it changes to 1 when i put the mouse on it in the script but it doesnt work so if anybody can help me, pls go ahead and help me and i dont think its a problem with the browser (i use firefox) and the javascript is enabled pls help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>yaz</title>
    <style>
        div {
            opacity:.5;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('div').mouseenter(function () {
         $('div').fadeTo('fast', 1);
        });
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
            <div>hello</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle where it works correctly, with JQuery included as @adeneo recommended.

http://jsfiddle.net/wK46p/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('div').mouseenter(function () {
    $('div').fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
});
```

To include JQuery, add the following code in your  (you can put it right after you include your CSS if you want):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work :( maybe its the browser or the laptops problem, what do you think, and would it be a problem from the laptop or browser.

Comment: well sorry, but it works on the link you  sent me , it works just fine but when i copy it into my file (my script) and also did the same to the css. then when i open it with firefox it doesnt work

Comment: maybe i just cant see it but you can so its actually working.

Comment: but no i can see it but not like when i open the html file instead its when i open it from the fiddle

Comment: Can you post your whole code? There might be an issue with another bit of JQuery causing everything to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You did not include jQuery first.  Add this code to your `<head>` section after your stylesheet link, directly above the `<script>` code you already have that does the fading:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```